# Конвертация временных слепков TimeStamp из строки VARCHAR(50) в поле типа TimeStamp(6) в Teradata

Tags: timestamp, teradata

Есть данные слепков времени, полученные из БД Оракл,
в Терадату они легкли в поле VARCHAR в виде

'02-DEC-21 01.06.07.000000 PM'

Нужно положить в другое поле Терадаты с типом TIMESTAMP(6) в виде
'2021-12-02 13.06.07.000000'
Здесь час '01 PM' должен явно преобразоваться в '13'

'02-DEC-21 01.06.07.000000 PM' -> '2021-12-02 13.06.07.000000'

select CAST('02-DEC-21 01.06.07.000000 PM' as TIMESTAMP(6) FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.S(6)'
from a
не работает...

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: переведите пожалуйста вопрос на русский язык, или задайте его на соответствующем ресурсе